WordPress - 500 Internal Server Error (Un Authorized)
I am facing an annoying issue with my WordPress website. It started with the error in the screenshot below when I installed a new plugin. I get an unauthorized error.
I did not care about that error since the plugin used to install fine and it was not blocking anything.
However, recently, one of the plugins, FunnelKit, started causing 500 Internal Server Errors that blocked me from performing critical website actions. Here is an example of one action and the response I see when doing developer tools.
So, it is similar to the authorization error I see when installing a plugin.
I tried replicating the same call using Postman (by exporting the HAR file from the browser), and it worked!
I use Hostinger for hosting, and I enabled the logging but nothing interesting.
Any pointer?

Please don't post images of code or errors!

Removed the images. Thanks.

Removing the image removes (important) information from your question, better to replace them with text, so people can easily copy/search etc. Thanks

I was able to find the error by running the command below in the SSH at the plugins folder.
grep -RF "Un Authorized!"

The "Un Authorized!" message was in the body of the 500 Internal Server Error.
